# trac require field to be set on resolution of a ticket

Tags: trac

Is it possible to require a field to be set on resolution of a ticket? I ran into TracTicketValidatorPlugin, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for b.c. it validates a field for all states. I just want to validate a field for a single state -- closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... it validates a field for all states.

[TicketValidatorPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketValidatorPlugin) validates for the specified states. The following works to require `milestone` to be nonempty when moving a ticket to closed:

```
[ticketvalidator]
closed.required = milestone
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah crap, there seems to be some namespace conflict on plugin load between this (TicketValidatorPlugin) and TracTicketValidatorPlugin....

Comment: I can fix the namespace collision if you [open a ticket](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketValidatorPlugin).

Comment: Thanks, ticket created [here](https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/13406#ticket). Let me know if I need to add any more detail. I believe the reproduction steps are straightforward.